# Edit woocommerce surcharge fee snippet code

Tags: php, woocommerce, transactions, checkout, code-snippets

I would like to know how I can modify the code so that all transactions have a percentage surcharge and exclude France?

```
 * Add a standard $ value surcharge to all transactions in cart / checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_add_surcharge' ); 
function wc_add_surcharge() { 
global $woocommerce; 

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
return;

$county = array('US');
// change the $fee to set the surcharge to a value to suit
$fee = 1.00;

if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) : 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $fee, true, 'standard' );  
endif;
}
```

I found the code on the  [woocommerce site](https://woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/)

Thank you for your response.

Comment: `$county = array('US');`  - from what I can see here, you should be able to just change this to the country of your choice.  Or at least that is the first thing that jumps out to try.  `if ( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ) : `  this says if the customers shipping address is in this array then add the fee.  So you want to add the `!in_array` not to the front of that.  If customers country is NOT in this array then give them the fee, then change the array to whatever country codes you don't want the fee to apply to

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted by reworking the code, is it gives this:

```
//Ajouter un supplément à votre paiement en fonction du pays de livraison exclu france
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' ); 
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() { 
    global $woocommerce; 

    if ( is_admin() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $county = ['FR']; //france
    // change the $fee to set the surcharge to a value to suit
    
    $percentage = 0.025;
    if ( !in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ){
        $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Frais de transaction', $surcharge, true, '' );
    }
}
```

All that's left is to change the following country for those they don't want to put charges on their country!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this based off how I am reading the code at least.  Can't really test it but it seemed simple enaugh.

```
* Add a standard $ value surcharge to all transactions in cart / checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','wc_add_surcharge' ); 

function wc_add_surcharge() { 
    global $woocommerce; 

    if ( is_admin() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $county = ['FR']; //france
    // change the $fee to set the surcharge to a value to suit
    $fee = 1.00;

    if ( !in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), $county ) ){  //add the ! to exclude only countries in the list
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $fee, true, 'standard' );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overload fees are fixed, ideally there should be price tiers

Example from 01€ to 55€ =0.35€
56 to 150€ = 1.00€ ...

In any case the code works on my site and excludes France.